# Failed to run service as console application

Tags: java, service, tomcat7, windows-xp

I've installed tomcat version 7.0.57 on my windows server 2008 R2 standard service pack 1

i followed the instructions on this link to create a new service "LexifoneServer1"

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

The configuration i used in tomcat is:

```
Classpath
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin\commons-daemon.jar
Java Options:
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf\logging.properties
```

Now i maneged to create the service (i think)
but when i run the service i get this error , any ideas?

C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin> tomcat7 //TS//LexifoneServer1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/s
tartup/Bootstrap
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstr
ap
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Failed to run service as console application

Answer (score 0):

Found it, i needed to create a GUI application for each service, set the parameters and start it.